# MacOS Sierra 10.12.1 - selenium - which version of Python?

Tags: python, macos

I plan to install Python and Selenium on MacOS 10.12.1. 
What would be the better choice - Python 2.7 or 3.6.5? On windows I use 2.7, because I read that it works faster. But are there any proven obstacles while working with Python 3 and Selenium on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Python 3 for quite a long time now. There is not really a performance issue that is quite noticeable. I would suggest Python 3 or which ever is the newer one because as they keep developing they will be adding new things that you might need and remove some older vulnerabilities. I would suggest you upgrade to Python 3. There might be some getting used to the new syntax but it can be quickly come over as you keep developing.

Comment: Thank you kindly for opinion of experience :)

Comment: Sure no problem. Hope this helped tho.